# Unable to properly connect to Redis in Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, tcp, redis, kubernetes

On my macOS (not using Minikube), I have modeled my Kubernetes cluster after [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/storage/redis) example, which means I have executed this verbatim and in this order:

```
# Adding my own service to redix-proxy
kubectl create -f ./redis/redis-service.yaml

# Create a bootstrap master
kubectl create -f examples/storage/redis/redis-master.yaml

# Create a service to track the sentinels
kubectl create -f examples/storage/redis/redis-sentinel-service.yaml

# Create a replication controller for redis servers
kubectl create -f examples/storage/redis/redis-controller.yaml

# Create a replication controller for redis sentinels
kubectl create -f examples/storage/redis/redis-sentinel-controller.yaml

# Scale both replication controllers
kubectl scale rc redis --replicas=3
kubectl scale rc redis-sentinel --replicas=3

# Adding my own NodeJS web client server
kubectl create -f web-deployment.yaml
```

The only difference is in `redis-proxy.yaml` I used the image `image: kubernetes/redis-proxy` instead of `image: kubernetes/redis-proxy:v2` because I wasn't able to pull the latter.

These are the objects I pass to [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) to create my Redis instances (one for sessions and one as the main one):

**config.js**

```
main: {
  host: 'redis',
  port: 6379,
  db: 5
},
session: {
  host: 'redis',
  port: 6379,
  db: 6
}
```

---

### Error logs:

In my web client `web-3448218364-sf1q0` pod, I get this repeated in the logs:

```
INFO: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Connected to Redis event
WARN: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Redis Connection Error:  { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
INFO: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Connected to Redis event
WARN: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Redis Connection Error:  { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
INFO: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Connected to Redis event
WARN: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Redis Connection Error:  { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
WARN: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Redis Connection Error:  { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT', code: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
WARN: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Redis Connection Error:  { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT', code: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
WARN: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Redis Connection Error:  { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT', code: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
WARN: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Redis Connection Error:  { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT', code: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }
INFO: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Connected to Redis event
WARN: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Redis Connection Error:  { [Error: read ECONNRESET] code: 'ECONNRESET', errno: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' }
INFO: ctn/53 on web-3448218364-sf1q0: Connected to Redis event
```

In my Redis `redis-proxy` pod, I get this repeated in the logs:

```
Error connecting to read: dial tcp :0: connection refused
```

---

**Cluster info:**

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME                      CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes                10.91.240.1     <none>           443/TCP          2d
redis                     10.91.251.170   <none>           6379/TCP         31m
redis-sentinel            10.91.250.118   <none>           26379/TCP        31m
web                       10.91.240.16    <none>           80/TCP           31m

$ kubectl get po
NAME                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
redis-2frd0                 1/1       Running   0          34m
redis-master                2/2       Running   0          34m
redis-n4x6f                 1/1       Running   0          34m
redis-proxy                 1/1       Running   0          34m
redis-sentinel-k8tbl        1/1       Running   0          34m
redis-sentinel-kzd66        1/1       Running   0          34m
redis-sentinel-wlzsb        1/1       Running   0          34m
web-3448218364-sf1q0        1/1       Running   0          34m

$ kubectl get deploy
NAME        DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
web         1         1         1            1           39m
```

**Question 1**) Now, I need to actually connect my application to a Redis pod. I should be connecting to the `redis-proxy` pod right? So, I created this `redis-service.yaml` service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    name: redis-proxy
    role: proxy
```

I believe I have connected to `redis` at port 6379 since I usually will get another error message if this is so. Going into the bash shell of my web container `web-3448218364-sf1q0`, I see the `printenv` variables of `REDIS_SERVICE_PORT=6379` and `REDIS_SERVICE_HOST=10.91.251.170`.

**Question 2**) From my error logs, what does it mean by `dial tcp :0:`? From my interactive Kubernetes console under Services and in the Internal Endpoints column, I see this for the `redis` service:

```
redis:6379 TCP
redis:0 TCP
```

Is this `0 TCP` related to that? All of my services have 0 TCP listed in the console, but as you can see, not from the CLI in `kubectl get svc`.

Comment: Please connect your redis server to redis master and try again. About 0 tcp, Do you see this in your `printenv`?

Answer (score 10):

Always the first thing to check when a kubernetes service does not behave as expected is to check the endpoints of the corresponding service. In your case `kubectl get ep redis`.

If my assumption is correct it should show you something like this

```
NAME      ENDPOINTS   AGE
redis     <none>      42d
```

This means that your service does not select/match any pods.

In your service spec there is the key `selector:` this selector has to match the labels of the actual deployment you have. You are selecting for all pods with the labels `name: redis-proxy` and `role: proxy` which are potentially not matching any pod.

You can run `kubectl get pod --show-labels=true` to show the labels on the pods and change your service accordingly.

I don't know what the port 0 means in this context. Sometimes it is used to do only DNS resolution with the service.

Answer (score 0):

From the deployment you posted above:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    name: redis
    redis-sentinel: "true"
    role: master
  name: redis-master
spec:
  containers:
    - name: master
      image: k8s.gcr.io/redis:v1
      env:
        - name: MASTER
          value: "true"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "0.1"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /redis-master-data
          name: data
    - name: sentinel
      image: kubernetes/redis:v1
      env:
        - name: SENTINEL
          value: "true"
      ports:
        - containerPort: 26379
  volumes:
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
```

You can see the container port of the sentinel is `26379`

Thus in the service (from the example)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: sentinel
    role: service
  name: redis-sentinel
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 26379
      targetPort: 26379
  selector:
    redis-sentinel: "true"
```

It again uses port `26379`

From the ioredis docs (host modified for your use case):

```
var redis = new Redis({
  sentinels: [{ host: 'redis-sentinel', port: 26379 }],
  name: 'mymaster'
});

redis.set('foo', 'bar');
```

The sentinel is not technically a proxy, ioredis first connects to the sentinel to find our which node is the master, then is given connection info for that node.

tl;dr;

Change the service back to the one used in the example, and use `redis-sentinel` as host and `26379` for port.